# Makefile question: how to make several analogous rules into one

Tags: make, makefile

I'm wondering if there's a way to make one rule out of the following several rules which are all similar in a Makefile that I have to edit:

```
$(OBJECT_BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(OBJECT_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(OBJECT_BUILD_DIR)/%.d
    @echo ........... Compiling $<
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(OBJECT_CFLAGS)
$(PROPERTIES_BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(PROPERTIES_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(PROPERTIES_BUILD_DIR)/%.d
    @echo ........... Compiling $<
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(PROPERTIES_CFLAGS)
$(WRAPPER_BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(WRAPPER_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(WRAPPER_BUILD_DIR)/%.d
    @echo ........... Compiling $<
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(WRAPPER_CFLAGS)
$(SOCKET_BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(SOCKET_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(SOCKET_BUILD_DIR)/%.d
    @echo ........... Compiling $<
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(SOCKET_CFLAGS)
```

Notice, aside from the variable name, the rule is exactly the same.  Is there a nifty makefile trick I can use here?

FYI, *.d are themselves makefiles that are generated by g++ and describe the dependency of a cpp file.

thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that, Makefile commands seem to screw up formatting, can someone help me out here?